# ybar interval width ignored

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

Following [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366758/40803) for custom `xtick`, I set `ybar interval` in the plot rather than in the axis, but the relative width option (`0.7`) seems to be ignored.

1. How can I set the width? (It may be best not to, but I want to experiment.)
2. Why do I keep getting an "overfull \hbox" warning.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
    month   count
    1998-01-01  487
    1998-02-01  421
    1998-03-01  459
    1998-04-01  509
    1998-05-01  496
    1998-06-01  479
    1998-07-01  396
    1998-08-01  451
    1998-09-01  441
    1998-10-01  574
    1998-11-01  532
    1998-12-01  472
    1999-01-01  413
    1999-02-01  426
    1999-03-01  467
    1999-04-01  483
    1999-05-01  383
    1999-06-01  368
    1999-07-01  410
    1999-08-01  410
    1999-09-01  393
    1999-10-01  437
    1999-11-01  445
    1999-12-01  401
    2000-01-01  428
    2000-02-01  404
    2000-03-01  478
    2000-04-01  489
    2000-05-01  393
    2000-06-01  391
    2000-07-01  414
    2000-08-01  420
    2000-09-01  392
    2000-10-01  460
    2000-11-01  466
    2000-12-01  405
    2001-01-01  0
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        width=5in,
        height=3in,
        date coordinates in=x,
        xtick={1998-01-01, 1999-01-01, 2000-01-01},
        ybar,
        xticklabel=\year,
        ymin=0,
        date ZERO=1998-01-01,
]
\addplot+ [
        ybar interval=0.7,
] table [x=month] {data.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Regarding 2, the default `\textwidth` in the `article` class is 345pt, which is about 4.77 in, and your diagram is about 5in wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `\addplot [ybar interval]..` you get `/tikz/ybar interval`, which does not have an option for the relative width. But when you do `\begin{axis}[ybar interval]` you get `/pgfplots/ybar interval` which does have the relative width option. When added to the `axis` options, that also affects the ticks, which is the reason for using `\addplot [ybar interval]` in the linked post I think.

You can do `\addplot +[/pgfplots/ybar interval=0.7] table [x=month] {data.txt};` which lets you use the relative width setting, without modifying the ticks. Whether there are any  drawbacks to this I don't know.

Regarding the width, my comment on your question was a bit inaccurate. Actually the plot is narrower than `\textwidth`, but the `tikzpicture` is indented with the standard paragraph indentation, which moves it right by 15pt. Adding `\noindent` before `\begin{tikzpicture}` will remove the indentation, but perhaps more appropriate to use a `center` environment?

In the example below I added the `showframe` package to indicate the borders of the text block, you'll want to remove that. I also added the `enlarge x limits` setting, to reduce the whitespace inside the axis a bit.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,showframe}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
    month   count
    1998-01-01  487
    1998-02-01  421
    1998-03-01  459
    1998-04-01  509
    1998-05-01  496
    1998-06-01  479
    1998-07-01  396
    1998-08-01  451
    1998-09-01  441
    1998-10-01  574
    1998-11-01  532
    1998-12-01  472
    1999-01-01  413
    1999-02-01  426
    1999-03-01  467
    1999-04-01  483
    1999-05-01  383
    1999-06-01  368
    1999-07-01  410
    1999-08-01  410
    1999-09-01  393
    1999-10-01  437
    1999-11-01  445
    1999-12-01  401
    2000-01-01  428
    2000-02-01  404
    2000-03-01  478
    2000-04-01  489
    2000-05-01  393
    2000-06-01  391
    2000-07-01  414
    2000-08-01  420
    2000-09-01  392
    2000-10-01  460
    2000-11-01  466
    2000-12-01  405
    2001-01-01  0
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        width=5in,
        height=3in,
        date coordinates in=x,
        xtick={1998-01-01, 1999-01-01, 2000-01-01},
        ybar,
        xticklabel=\year,
        ymin=0,
        date ZERO=1998-01-01,
        enlarge x limits=0.03
]
\addplot +[/pgfplots/ybar interval=0.7] table [x=month] {data.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```